# Calling Model method inside template file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning to create a blog website using django. I encountered an issue while calling my model method inside template file. The site is not displaying contents inside the body. It was working fine when i used article.body but its not working when i use article.snippet.

models.py file:-

...

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]
```

...

articles_list.html file:-

...

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Articles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Articles List</h1>
    <div class="articles">
      {% for article in articles %}
      <div class="article">
        <h2><a href="">{{article.title}}</a></h2>
        <p>{{article.body.snippet}}</p>
        <p>{{article.date}}</p>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

...

views.py file:-

...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Article

def articles_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'articles/articles_list.html', {'articles': articles})
```

...

There is no error displayed in code but still there is no output inside body tag.

Comment: assuming the indents are correct in your code; as shown here in stack overflow the str and snippet are not part of Article.

Comment: also you just need {{article.snippet}} not {{article.body.snippet}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a built-in [Slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter in your template

like this

```
<p<{{ article.body|slice:":50" }}</p>
```

But for some reason, if you want to call any model methods from the templates you can use @property decorator to access it.

like this

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]
```

Comment: Better alternative than `slice`: [`truncatechars` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah sure `truncatechars` is an alternative option, I don't usually use it because it adds an ellipsis (three dots) after the truncated characters. :)

Comment: All the solution worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
<p>{{article.snippet}}</p>
```

instead of:

```
<p>{{article.body.snippet}}</p>
```

because **snippet** is a method in the same model so you can call it directly, and body is not a ForeignKey

Comment: This was not working until i used property decorator.